# Why is `last` Aggregation Slower than `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`?

Tags: sql, time-series, questdb

I'm getting a big difference in performance when selecting the most recent timestamp from a table in QuestDB using these two queries.

This query takes ~46ms.

```
SELECT timestamp FROM <table_name> ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

This one takes ~165ms.

```
SELECT last(timestamp) FROM <table_name>
```

Both queries return the same, but when using `last` is way slower. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` is highly optimized, especially when using the designated timestamp. Data in questdb tables is physically stored sorted by incremental timestamp, so we can efficiently retrieve the most recent entry.

The `last` aggregation function is internally treated as a `GROUP BY`, so it needs to do a full scan to get the last value. At the moment QuestDB has no optimisations for no-op cases (i.e. when there is no meaningful aggregation). For those queries, you are better off rewriting with an alternative like you did.

By the way, QuestDB accepts a negative limit, so you can do

```
SELECT timestamp FROM <table_name> LIMIT -1
```

To access the last row, as data is sorted by incremental designated timestamp.

There is a related [issue on GitHub to optimize First and Last aggregate functions](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/4231) automatically, but at the moment your best option is a query rewrite